# Multidimensional arrays to insert for one row

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have three arrays that look like this:

**ingredientQTY** is the first input box in each row, **measurements** is the select/dropdown in each row, and **ingredientsNAME** is the last input box in each row. As you can see, there can be infinite numbers of **ingredientQTY's, ingredientNAME's, and measurements**.

[image: picture]

When I send them to my php script, the data is in arrays like:

```
IngredientQTY
(
  [0] => 5 //The first row 
  [1] => 5 //The next rows value
)   
Measurements
(
  [0] => Bunch  //The first row
  [1] => Bunch  //The next rows value
)   
IngredientName
(
  [0] => 5   //The first row
  [1] => 5   //The next rows value
)
```

I'm trying to upload them to a table called ingredients that has 3 columns: `ingredientNAME`, `ingredientQTY`, and `measurements`.

In my php script, I'm combining them into a multidimensional array, which is assigned to `$ingredientsROW`:

```php
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
      $value = $this->input->post($key);
      $ingredientQTY = $this->input->post('ingredientQTY');
      $measurements = $this->input->post('measurements');
      $ingredientNAME = $this->input->post('ingredientNAME');
      $ingredientsROW[] = array($ingredientQTY, $measurements, $ingredientNAME);
      break;
}
```

My question is: How can I get group all the first row of form elements (which means the first `ingredientQTY`, the first `measurements` dropdown and the first `ingredientNAME` and insert them into a row?

The only way I could think of is to have one insert where I insert `ingredientQTY`, then look up the id of the row I just inserted and use two mysql updates to enter for the same row, but I'm pretty sure there is more efficient ways of going about this.

Comment: Are you using JavaScript for the "Add Ingredient" button?

Comment: a foreach loop that breaks himself at the first loop doesn't look quite correct to me...

Comment: Note that the select boxes aren't clickable. (FF on Linux)

Comment: @FritsvanCampen Yeah, that parts already working. I could post the code if it would help?

Comment: Not that it's any of my business but I cannot see how calling the table 'ingredients' makes any sense in this context. 'Inventory' I could understand, but 'ingredients'? Nah, I don't get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate through the data and create an array like this:

```
for ($i = 0, $count = count($ingredientQTY); $i < $count; $i++) {
   $rows[] = array(
       'QTY'         => $ingredientQTY[$i],
       'measurement' =>  $measurements[$i],
       'name'        => $ingredientNAME[$i]
   );
}
```

With this array you can create the insert quite easily and insert whole rows.

Answer (score 2):

Would something like this work?

```
foreach($_POST['IngredientQTY'] as $index=>$qty)
    mysql_query("insert into ingredients ".
                 "set IngredientQTY='".addslashes($qty)."'".
                 ", measurements ='".addslashes($_POST['measurements'][$index])."'".
                 ", ingredientNAME ='".addslashes($_POST['ingredientNAME'][$index])."');
```

Comment: Yes, that should work too. Just please remember to use `mysqli_` functions instead of `mysql_` as the latter ones are deprecated. When using MySql you can also use `mysqli_escape_string()` in place of `addslashes()`.